# Converting parametric equation to Cartesian

Tags: algebraic-geometry, parametric

How can I convert these parametric equations into a Cartesian equation (I think that is what its called). Wolfram alpha doesn't seem like it [can handle this one.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3D%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A%20cos%28t%29%20%2B%20cos%28-6t%29%20%2F%2F%5D%2C%20y%3D%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A%20sin%28t%29%20%2B%20sin%28-6t%29%20%2F%2F%5D%20in%20terms%20of%20t)
$$
x=\cos{t}+\cos{-6t}\\
y=\sin{t}+\sin{-6t}
$$

Is there a name for this operation?

Comment: Parametric equations often aren't solvable as a single function of x, and this particular one has multiple y values for x, and x values for y, so it cant be solved as a single y=f(x) or x=f(y) equation.

Comment: Second members have in argument "$-6t$"?

Comment: While one can't give a represenation $y=f(x)$ for the whole curve, one can probably give a representation of the cuve as the zero locus of a single polynomial $f(x,y)$, which should be of degree a multiple of seven. The algebro-geometric approach here would be to write $\cos(t)=w$ and $\sin(t)=z$, use the triple/double angle formulae to write $\cos -6t$ and $\sin -6t$ as polynomials in $w,z$, and then eliminate $w$ and $z$ from the equations via elimination theory and the relation $w^2+z^2=1$. It will likely be a bit long, so if someone else wants to give it a shot before I do, go for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for an implicit equation for this parametric plane curve. The process of turning a system of parametric equations into a system of implicit equations is called implicitization. See $\S3.3$ of Cox, Little, and O'Shea's *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms* for more on this.

Let $u = \cos(t)$ and $v = \sin(t)$. Using de Moivre's formula, we have
\begin{align*}
\cos(6t) &= T_6(\cos(t)) = 32u^6 - 48u^4 + 18u^2 - 1\\
\sin(6t) &= \sin(t) \, U_6(\cos(t)) = v(32u^5 - 32u^3 + 6u)
\end{align*}
where $T_6$ and $U_6$ are the Chebyshev polynomials of the first- and second kind, respectively. (Depending on your indexing, the second polynomial might be $U_5$.)

We form the ideal
$$
(u^2 + v^2 - 1, x - (u + 32u^6 - 48u^4 + 18u^2 - 1), y - (v - v(32u^5 - 32u^3 + 6u)))
$$
in $\mathbb{Q}[u,v,x,y]$ and compute a Gröbner basis under the elimination ordering. ([This can be done in *SageMath*](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwdjcsKgzAQRfeF_sPsTOwo-Kh0Ubvozl11K1oUgwRSA5GE-PeduLlz5nLgdunTokOPxwtq-Gh1bPonJ9XJbWVtiyWCNoswdaSEj_j10pAmFzEp1tsxhxs4ygQyBE-HWWqKPLZjRV_5ICipyQKcGkc4gucoXMxO9U58QkFqFVvOBxp601CTrkaLeRPmO0-73Fno-yQb_uDAL7s=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).)  The last generator in this basis is
\begin{align*}
f(x,y) &:= x^{12} + 6 x^{10} y^{2} - 5 x^{10} + 15 x^{8} y^{4} - 25 x^{8} y^{2} + 5 x^{8} - 2 x^{7} + 20 x^{6} y^{6} - 50 x^{6} y^{4}\\
& \qquad + 20 x^{6} y^{2} + 42 x^{5} y^{2} + 15 x^{4} y^{8} - 50 x^{4} y^{6} + 30 x^{4} y^{4} - 70 x^{3} y^{4} + 6 x^{2} y^{10}\\
& \qquad - 25 x^{2} y^{8} + 20 x^{2} y^{6} + 14 x y^{6} + y^{12} - 5 y^{10} + 5 y^{8}
\end{align*}
so the implicit equation of the curve is $f(x,y) = 0$. Here are the [parametric plot](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwrSyzSUC9R1-TlqlCwVUjOL9Yo0VTQBjN0zbRKgOKVQPHizDyIOIgBFS9ILErMTS0pykyOL8jJL9HQqNCp1NRR0CjR0TXVMdXUBABXVBi0&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) and [implicit plot](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNj90KgzAMhe8F3yF3_lWoaa3e9FWUMRAKbsomo337JV0Lu-p3TpqT5HN71ZUXoWrKYgMLfhkQOjAtgWzDgtDDGAW5A9NMriYXs-D_kdmkdyKNksBQ0XB_Fvq_wm2a_49JxHRNYs49OgZ0oLLguRMLldJ4TySm9dJGGAPSHEwBg259wsAH8k3hdxPDXBbuce7u7q713I-r3qyVAmoveiVUQxQycXk9D_e83naSsvkCmT9REg==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) for comparison.